# disable closing child window in silverlight 4 after you press the hotkey CTRL + SHIFT + F4

Tags: c#, silverlight, childwindow

I am creating a child window to login in my application. I already disabled the X button, however, if the user types on the keyboard CTRL + SHIFT + F4 closes the window and jump the login phase. I can not stop it. can anyone help me please?

Comment: sorry, after i posted the answer, i find the solution: in handler of event Closing of the ChildWindow i put this code                      e.Cancel = !((bool)DialogResult);  and all works.

Comment: You may experience difficulty closing the form using the above.  More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943/how-to-disable-alt-f4-closing-form.  Applies to WinForms but should set you on the right path.