# How do I disable ALT+F4 from closing but pressing H will close the program

Tags: c#, winforms

For example letting this work:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.H)
    {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

While I am disabling Alt+f4 from working I can't use `e.Cancel = true;` because it disables hitting the key H from closing the program.

Comment: You must disable system menu item instead of canceling close.

Comment: What do you want to do when user clicks close button or select close from context menu ?

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

**Solution 1:**

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.H)
        {
            this.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else if (keyData == Keys.Alt | keyData == Keys.F4)
        {
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Alt | e.KeyCode==Keys.F4)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.H)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Downvoter: could you please explain me the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing);
}
```

This way you cancel the close only when the user is trying to close the form through the user interface.

Check this: [How to Disable Alt + F4 closing form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943/how-to-disable-alt-f4-closing-form)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You're right. Sudhakar answer is the right one, assuming you will allow the user to close the form with the Close Button.

Comment: Yes, using close button and also windows context menu too. If user wants to prevent those also this is the way to go:)

Answer (score 1):

What about setting some global variable to close?

```
bool closeForm = false;
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.H)
    {
        closeForm = true;
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

and in your FormClosing event, just check against the variable like so

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!closeForm)
       e.Cancel = true;
}
```