# How do prevent any Form from closing using alt + F4

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox, formclosing

This is not a duplicate of *[How to Disable Alt + F4 closing form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943/how-to-disable-alt-f4-closing-form)*. Please read why.

I have made a custom MessageBox under my main Form.

[image]

And have set "Aight" button click listener as:

```
private void Aight_buton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dr = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();
}
```

The same is the case with the "X" button. Following the above question's answer I could have done this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing;
}
```

but since I am using `Close()` under the `Aight_buton_Click` it still registers as `e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing;`. So hitting the key doesn't close my form (a custom messagebox) nor does <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. I would like to know how specifically I can prevent only <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> closes and not the `Close()` closes. And please I would rather not use `ModifierKeys` as it is not the most appropriate not the smartest way to handle this situation.

Comment: You can use an additional flag, no?

Comment: @TaW I'm more or less new to C#. I'd be glad if you could elaborate. An additional flag checking what exactly?

Comment: Create a class level `bool doClose = false;`  You set it to true in the button click and test it in closing.

Comment: I am pretty sure that unless you repurpose the Alt+F4 key sequence, it's always going to generate the close message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handle `Atl+F4` by your self and set it handled.

In the form constructor first set

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Then handle the keyDown event

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
     {
         e.Handled = true;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've seen many answers in other forums as well but all answers talk about a workaround making the buttons close the form just like Zohar's answer but only this answer prevents Alt + F4 closing.

Answer (score 5):

Add a bool field to the form, set it to `true` in the `Aight_buton_Click` method, and in the `Form1_FormClosing` only prevent the form from being closed if that field is false.

So on the form level:

```
private bool _isAightButonClicked;
```

Set it to true in the `Aight_buton_Click` method:

```
private void Aight_buton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _isAightButonClicked = true;
    dr = DialogResult.OK;
    Close(); 
}
```

Use it in the `Form1_FormClosing` method:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing && !_isAightButonClicked;
}
```

Comment: Zohar Peled answer is correct to prevent closing form with `boolean` and `Form1_FormClosing` event but since i needed window that couldn't be closed i assume you do not want to let user close it in any way so other problem you will have is that user could close window from Task Manager.

Solution to this problem is to add handler for `Form1_FormClosed`

So if form is closed (somehow) and your `boolean == false` create new form again. This way i prevented user to close it any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works great:

```
Private Sub FrmMikeStats_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        'Stop Alt-F4 from closing this program ***************************************************************************
        '*****************************************************************************************************************
        If ModifierKeys = Keys.Alt Or ModifierKeys = Keys.F4 Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).